# What does this number colon [5:] statement mean in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm looking at some VB.NET code that's been ported from VB6, and I saw this method.

```
    Private Sub txtDefaultSlope_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDefaultSlope.TextChanged
        Dim temp = Me.txtDefaultSlope.Text
        Dim slope As Double
5:
        If (Double.TryParse(temp, slope)) Then
           ...
        End If

    End Sub
```

What does the 5: statement mean in line 4 of the method?

Comment: It is a [goto label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/69whc95c.aspx)! DO NOT USE IT! IT IS EVIL! It breaks any good programming practices created in the past and those that will be created in future.

Comment: [GoTo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_goto_statement.htm) alias  [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

Comment: @KonradKokosa well technically its just a label. I agree that you should never, ever use GoTo, but a label by itself isn't really evil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just a Label. From the code it appears that it is not used anywhere, usually it can be used with a [`GoTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69whc95c.aspx) statement.

You should see: [How to: Label Statements (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh9dwts7.aspx)